# JSONPath get value from map within a table

Tags: java, jsonpath

I have a JSON string as follows (simplified):

```
{
   "data":{
      "fruit":[
         {
            "role":[
               {
                  "role":"passive"
               }
            ],
            "objectType":"apple"
         },
         {
            "role":[
               {
                  "role":"active"
               }
            ],
            "objectType":"orange"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I would like to get `objectType` value where role is `active`. In this example the result would be `orange`. I've come up with the following code, however it doesn't return anything. How do I fix this?

```
$.data.fruit[?(@.role.role == 'active')]
```

Note that the number of elements in fruit array may vary and there is no guarantee that the last element would be correct.

Comment: just add another `.` to your 2nd `role`: `$..data.fruit[?(@.role..role=="active")].objectType`. It's basically the short form of the more logical `$..data.fruit[?(@.role[?(@.role=="active")])].objectType`.

Comment: One minor change had to be implemented, thought.

Comment: Out of curiosity - what was it?

Comment: `$.data.fruit[?('active' in @..role..role)].objectType`. Please write an answer so that I can accept it. Without your input I couldn't have made it. No Gatling implementation was needed. In fact, I couldn't find it:)

Comment: That's what I dislike about jsonpath - it's so finicky.. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At OP's request, here's the final, final answer!

```
$.data.fruit[?('active' in @..role..role)].objectType
```

Answer (score -2):

On the off chance that it is a number, progressive levels in the stringification will each be indented by this many space characters (up to 10).

In the event that it is a string, progressive levels will be indented by this string (or its initial ten characters).

Comment: How does this answer my question?